# How can I suppress a notice error in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to suppress notices in the codeigniter error log during a certain cronjob. I've tried using the @ in front of the line, but it still prints the notice in the log:

This is the row that is generating the notice:

```
@$resultarray[1][2]++;
```

The notice: *... Severity: Notice  --> Undefined offset: 1 ...*

What am I doing wrong here?

(I'm using it well overthought, so please no messages claiming not to use @, thanks :) )

Comment: check with empty() or isset() if(isset($resultarray[1][2])) $resultarray[1][2]++

Comment: You can set `error_reporting(0);` on your top of that file to turn off all the errors for that particular file, but I will suggest you rather find the proper solution for the error and notices you getting.

Comment: It is royally stupid to not fix this. Just ignoring it is not a solution, and it will cause problems... that you may never know about, or if you do, have a very hard time fixing later on.

Comment: @Rakesh Sharma Of course I can fix it with those kinds of checks, and I might, but for now I am curious why it does not work.

Comment: @Rikesh: I am intererested in finding out why the @ sign in front of the line does not work.

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen: It is just a temporary script that I am using one time only, but I was hoping to find out why it does not work like this...

Comment: @Pim `@` sign is use to suppress warnings and not notice.

Comment: @Rikesh according to http://us3.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php it should also work with notices.

Answer (score 8):

To have PHP report all errors except E_Notice, call the PHP error_reporting function like so:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
```

I believe the best way to do this is to configure your index.php at the root of the application to first detect your application environment and then conditionally set which PHP errors are reported.

index.php

```
if (defined('ENVIRONMENT'))
{
  switch (ENVIRONMENT)
  {
    case 'development':
    case 'testing':
    case 'staging':
      error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
    break;

    case 'production':
      error_reporting(0);
    break;

    default:
      exit('The application environment is not set correctly.');
  }
}
```

See the official [PHP Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) about the error_reporting function for more configuration options.

Alternatively, you can just call the error_reporting function in the particular file you're using (whatever your cron job calls) and it'll overwrite the configuration with what you set in index.php. Here's a simple example using a controller:

```
class Sample_Controller extends CI_Controller {

  public function __construct()
  {
    parent::__construct();
    error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

In system/core/Common.php

```
function _exception_handler($severity, $message, $filepath, $line)
{
     // We don't bother with "strict" notices since they tend to fill up
     // the log file with excess information that isn't normally very helpful.
     // For example, if you are running PHP 5 and you use version 4 style
     // class functions (without prefixes like "public", "private", etc.)
     // you'll get notices telling you that these have been deprecated.
    if ($severity == E_STRICT || !error_reporting()) // <-- add || !error_reporting()
    {
        return;
    }

    $_error =& load_class('Exceptions', 'core');

    // Should we display the error? We'll get the current error_reporting
    // level and add its bits with the severity bits to find out.
    if (($severity & error_reporting()) == $severity)
    {
        $_error->show_php_error($severity, $message, $filepath, $line);
    }

    // Should we log the error?  No?  We're done...
    if (config_item('log_threshold') == 0)
    {
        return;
    }

    $_error->log_exception($severity, $message, $filepath, $line);
}

}
```

Add `|| !error_reporting()` and expressions with error control operator `@` will not be logged by CodeIgniter.

Answer (score 0):

Straight from the [docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)

```
<?php

// Turn off all error reporting
error_reporting(0);

// Report simple running errors
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE);

// Reporting E_NOTICE can be good too (to report uninitialized
// variables or catch variable name misspellings ...)
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE | E_NOTICE);

// Report all errors except E_NOTICE
// This is the default value set in php.ini
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);

// Report all PHP errors (see changelog)
error_reporting(E_ALL);

// Report all PHP errors
error_reporting(-1);

// Same as error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);

?>
```

In your php.ini Comment out,

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE | E_STRICT
error_reporting = E_COMPILE_ERROR|E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR|E_ER… _ERROR
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE
```

Comment: No need to comment something out and actually it can break things, if one just comments out the default setting for **all** scripts.

Comment: @GhostGambler I would rather actually have working code and not have to do this haha

Comment: If you agree that setting lower error reporting is a bad idea, why did you post your answer in the first place?

Comment: @GhostGambler because I thought I would give him the answer to the question regardless if it is right or wrong.

Comment: @OliverBS thanks for your answer, but I'm interested in finding out why the @ does not work. I'm not looking for a solutions that turns off error messages globally. Any thoughts on that?

Answer (score 0):

From http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php:

> If you have set a custom error handler function with set_error_handler()
>   then it will still get called, but this custom error handler can (and
>   should) call error_reporting() which will return 0 when the call that
>   triggered the error was preceded by an @.

However, CodeIgniter 2 doesn't do this. In order to hide @suppressed errors from CodeIgniter, you would need to edit the `_exception_handler` function in `system/core/Common.php`, to include these lines at the start:

```
if (error_reporting() == 0) {
  return;
}
```

As per the link above, `error_reporting()` will return 0 if the call that triggered the error was preceded by an @. This code will check for this, and prevent CodeIgniter from logging such errors.

Answer (score 0):

Go to config/constants then set
        defined('SHOW_DEBUG_BACKTRACE') OR define('SHOW_DEBUG_BACKTRACE', TRUE);to 
        defined('SHOW_DEBUG_BACKTRACE') OR define('SHOW_DEBUG_BACKTRACE', FALSE);